# Parameter estimation using reinforcement learning

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning, odeint

I want to do parameter estimation using reinforcement leaning. Basically I have Ordinary differential equation(ODE) **y' = acos(wt + d)*w**.Actual function (**y = asin(wt + d)**) So I want estimate **a**, **w** and **d**. I used scipy.integrate.odeint to solve this ODE.
In my program initially a, w and d randomly generated within some range. After that Agent(algorithm) take some action (action is just changing the value of a, w, d like fixed, increase or decrease so basically agent can take one action from 27 different action.).
After that environment solve the ode using odeint() then I calculate mean squared error as loss. I consider loss is negative reward. If loss is zero then done. 
State tuple are [a, w, d].
Please tell me am I on right direction? What should I can do next.I have one more doubt that is In machine learning after training we have one model and we have to test it so similarly How can we do it here if possible.
I have two file One is environment and other is agent.
**environment**

```
`import numpy as np 
import math
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import random

class solver():
    def get_experiment_data(self):      
        count = 0
        for i in self.time:    
            self.y_true[count] = self.data_generator_sin(2, 2 * math.pi/12, math.pi/4, i)
            count += 1
    def data_generator_sin(self,a, w, d, t):
        return a*math.sin(w*t + d)
    def reset(self):
        self.a = random.uniform(1.5,2.5)
        self.w = random.uniform(0.25,0.75)
        self.d = random.uniform(0.5, 0.8)
        self.loss = 0.0
        return [self.a, self.w, self.d]

    def step1(self, action):
        self.reward = 0
        self.done = 0
        #0 -> fixed, 1 -> increase, 2 -> decrease
        # awd
        # if action == 0:
        #   #000
        #   # self.a += self.a*0.1
        #   # self.w -= self.w*0.1
        #   # self.d -= self.d*0.1
        if action == 1:
            #001
            # self.a += self.a*0.1
            # self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 2:
            #002
            # self.a += self.a*0.1
            # self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d -= self.d*0.1
        elif action == 3:
            #010
            #self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w += self.w*0.1
            #self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 4:
            #011
            #self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w += self.w*0.1
            self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 5:
            #012
            #self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w += self.w*0.1
            self.d -= self.d*0.1
        elif action == 6:
            #020
            #self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w -= self.w*0.1
            #self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 7:
            #021
            #self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 8:
            #022
            #self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d -= self.d*0.1
        elif action == 9:
            #100
            self.a += self.a*0.1
            #self.w -= self.w*0.1
            #self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 10:
            #101
            self.a += self.a*0.1
            #self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 11:
            #102
            self.a += self.a*0.1
            #self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d -= self.d*0.1
        elif action == 12:
            #110
            self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w += self.w*0.1
            #self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 13:
            #111
            self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w += self.w*0.1
            self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 14:
            #112
            self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w += self.w*0.1
            self.d -= self.d*0.1
        elif action == 15:
            #120
            self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w -= self.w*0.1
            #self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 16:
            #121
            self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 17:
            #122
            self.a += self.a*0.1
            self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d -= self.d*0.1
        elif action == 18:
            #200
            self.a -= self.a*0.1
            #self.w += self.w*0.1
            #self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 19:
            #201
            self.a -= self.a*0.1
            #self.w += self.w*0.1
            self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 20:
            #202
            self.a -= self.a*0.1
            #self.w += self.w*0.1
            self.d -= self.d*0.1
        elif action == 21:
            #210
            self.a -= self.a*0.1
            self.w += self.w*0.1
            #self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 22:
            #211
            self.a -= self.a*0.1
            self.w += self.w*0.1
            self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 23:
            #212
            self.a -= self.a*0.1
            self.w += self.w*0.1
            self.d -= self.d*0.1
        elif action == 24:
            #220
            self.a -= self.a*0.1
            self.w -= self.w*0.1
            #self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 25:
            #221
            self.a -= self.a*0.1
            self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d += self.d*0.1
        elif action == 26:
            #222
            self.a -= self.a*0.1
            self.w -= self.w*0.1
            self.d -= self.d*0.1
        self.run_frame()

        state = [self.a, self.w, self.d]
        return self.reward, state, self.done
    def dydx(y, t, *args):
        a = args[0]
        w = args[1]
        d = args[2]
        return a * math.cos(w * t + d) * w
    def run_frame(self):
        parameter = (self.a, self.w, self.d)
        odeint_solver_data = odeint(self.dydx, 0, self.time, parameter).flatten()
        # print(type(odeint_solver_data))
        self.loss = np.square(np.subtract(odeint_solver_data,self.y_true)).mean() 
        self.reward = -self.loss
        # if self.loss < 0.5:
        #   self.done = 1
    def __init__(self):

        self.reward = 0
        self.done = False
        self.a = random.uniform(1.5,2.5)
        self.w = random.uniform(0.25,0.75)
        self.d = random.uniform(0.5, 0.8)
        self.loss = 0.0
        self.start = 0
        self.stop = 24
        self.step = 0.2
        #evenly spaced values within a given interval(0.1)
        self.time = np.arange(self.start, self.stop, self.step)
        self.y_true = np.zeros((len(self.time),), dtype=float)
        self.get_experiment_data()
        # print(self.a, self.w, self.d)
        # print(sel)`
**agent**
`from environment import solver
import random
import numpy as np
from keras import Sequential
from collections import deque
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.optimizers import adam

env = solver()
np.random.seed(0)


class DQN:
    """ Implementation of deep q learning algorithm """
    def __init__(self, action_space, state_space):
        self.action_space = action_space
        self.state_space = state_space
        self.epsilon = 1
        self.gamma = .95
        self.batch_size = 64
        self.epsilon_min = .01
        self.epsilon_decay = .995
        self.learning_rate = 0.01
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=100000)
        self.model = self.build_model()

    def build_model(self):

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(self.state_space,), activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_space, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def act(self, state):
        # print(state)
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return random.randrange(self.action_space)
        act_values = self.model.predict(state)
        return np.argmax(act_values[0])

    def replay(self):
        if len(self.memory) < self.batch_size:
            return

        minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, self.batch_size)
        states = np.array([i[0] for i in minibatch])
        actions = np.array([i[1] for i in minibatch])
        rewards = np.array([i[2] for i in minibatch])
        next_states = np.array([i[3] for i in minibatch])
        dones = np.array([i[4] for i in minibatch])

        states = np.squeeze(states)
        next_states = np.squeeze(next_states)

        targets = rewards + self.gamma*(np.amax(self.model.predict_on_batch(next_states), axis=1))*(1-dones)
        targets_full = self.model.predict_on_batch(states)

        ind = np.array([i for i in range(self.batch_size)])
        targets_full[[ind], [actions]] = targets

        self.model.fit(states, targets_full, epochs=1, verbose=0)
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay


def train_dqn(episode):

    loss = []
    agent = DQN(27, 3)
    for e in range(episode):
        state = env.reset()
        state = np.reshape(state, (1, 3))
        # print(state)
        score = 0
        max_steps = 1000
        for i in range(max_steps):
            action = agent.act(state)
            # print(type(action))
            reward, next_state, done = env.step1(action)
            score += reward
            next_state = np.reshape(next_state, (1, 3))
            agent.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
            state = next_state
            agent.replay()
            if done:
                print("episode: {}/{}, score: {}".format(e, episode, score))
                break
        print("episode : {}/{}, state : {}, reward : {},".format(e, episode, state, reward))
        loss.append(score)
    return loss


if __name__ == '__main__':

    ep = 100
    loss = train_dqn(ep)
    plt.plot([i for i in range(ep)], loss)
    plt.xlabel('episodes')
    plt.ylabel('reward')
    plt.show()
`
```